# Elementary Row Operations hoffman

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In Hoffman Linear Algebra, Chapter 1.3 Exercises, the following question is presented:

Find all solutions to the system of equations:

$(1 - i)X_1 - iX_2 = 0$

$2X_1 + (1-i)X_2=0$

In the solutions to this (using elementary row operations), this was given:

[picture of equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezgJf.png)

How did part 2 happen? Making all elements of row 1 zero?

Comment: Don't misspell a word in the title to avoid the system flagging it as a duplicate title. Come up with a better title instead.

Comment: Use Latex for better clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first row is simply a scaled-up version of the second row with the scalar being $(1-i)$. Since it is redundant information, it seems that they just made everything zero.

More specifically, $r_1\cdot (1-i)=r_2$ because $1\cdot (1-i)=1-i$ and $(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i)(1-i)=\frac{1}{2}(1-1-2i)=\frac{1}{2}(-2i)=-i$

Comment: how does i times i gives i not i^2?

Comment: You are correct. $i\cdot i=i^2$

To elaborate: $(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}i)(1-i)=\frac{1}{2}(1-i)\cdot (1-i)=\frac{1}{2}(1-i)^2=\frac{1}{2}(1^2+i^2-2(1)(i))=\frac{1}{2}(1-1-2i)=\frac{1}{2}(-2i)=-i$

Comment: i think it's still wrong

Comment: Yeah, I could be wrong. Can you point out where you see a mistake?

Comment: in the last part. where did i^2 go?

Comment: Oh, $i$ is defined to be the imaginary unit, or $\sqrt{-1}$. By definition, $i^2=-1$. Hope this helps!

Comment: isn't it like any other variable like x? are you sure it's imaginary unit? so if instead of i it was x, the answer would have been completely different?

Comment: I would say that it would be weird to use the variable $i$ instead of $x$ if there wasn't a special reason to do so. Usually, $i$ is the imaginary unit, too. Also, if you treat $i^2=-1$, the reasoning makes sense on why the first row would become zeros.